# Is it possible to decrypt an MD5 hash with the salt?

Tags: md5

I need to decrypt this hashed password: e59dc19f2a3a569417fa183696f91604 and have the salt: 4067. Is it possible to recover the password with this information?

Comment: Do you know how the salt and hash were applied?

Comment: Think about this for a minute: an md5 hash takes a string of arbitrary length and produces a string of constant length. This alone should tell you that it's impossible to reverse it. Why? Because there must be an infinite number of strings which would hash to that length: hashing is not encryption, it does not preserve information.

Comment: The whole point of _hashing_ is to make that impossible.

Comment: Well I introduce you guys to hashcat. Used it, decoded all MD5s with/without salt. This was the incorrect place to ask this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, hash algorithms are one way.

You can hash the original password again and see if the hash result match the previous one.

Comment: To the question "is it possible" the answer is yes. You might feel that "No" is the right answer because it's not feasible, but it would be good to explain why (e.g. give some examples of how hard it is or isn't).

Answer (score 14):

You mentioned the word *decrypt* in your question, so I wanted to just mention firstly that hashes are **not** a means encryption. Encryption is a two way process of encryption and decryption. It's a way of securing data in transit or stasis.

Hashes are a one way algorithm and cannot be *decrypted*. However, there are means of finding out what was hashed. If you do some research into *Rainbow tables*, you'll see that you simply need to build a list of texts (with a salt, in your case) and their corresponding hash.

Hashes and Encryption are like bread and icecream, respectively. You can heat up bread and get toast, but you **can't** cool down toast to get bread. You can heat up icecream to get cream, and you **can** cool it down again to get your icecream back.

Comment: actually love your analogy, +1 from me :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to decrypt this, but it is a long and laborious process. It's referred to as "brute-force", which means you would try a large (and by large, I mean significantly large dependent on the length of the password) number of inputs. Since the hash function is a one-way function that produces a non-random result, you will always map an input to the same output. So by using "brute-force", you're literally trying every possible combination and seeing if the hash produced is equal to the hash stored on the system (since you already know the salt). There are tools that do this such as John the Ripper (available on Kali Linux) but again, dependent on your computational power, it can take awhile.

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible to decrypt it. However, you may be able to crack it using the brute force method to find matching passwords in a dictionary.

Best tool to use would be hashcat.

Comment: "Best tool to use would be hashcat." - do you have any credible source for that? Also, there's no need to duplicate other answers

Answer (score -7):

I tried to decrypt a hash with salt, and it works but only with the same encrypt application or method (I mean with the same exact thing, if u encrypt it on a website, or an app you have to decrypt that on the very same place).

I hope that helps

Comment: hash is one way so couldn't have decrypted. Can compare but not decrypt